# How can I determine why my trigger does not run?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, triggers, workbench

```
   create database triggers;
    
    use triggers;
    
    create table if not exists Customers(
        custID INT unsigned not null auto_increment,
        age int,
        name varchar(30),
        primary key(custID)
    );
    
    delimiter //
    create trigger age_verify
    before insert on customers
    for each row
    if new.age < 0 then set new.age = 0;
    end if; //
    
    insert into Customers
    values (101, 27, 'James'),
    (102, -40, 'Ammy'),
    (103, 32, 'Ben'),
    (104, -39, 'Angela');
    
    select * from Customers;
```

For some reason my trigger in MySQL workbench does not run and when I run select * from customers it prints the negatives still and does not update the value. How can I debug this?

Comment: I tested your example code using MySQL 8.0, and it works fine. The trigger changes the negative values to 0 as expected. Can you clarify what `SELECT VERSION();` reports? Perhaps it works differently in the version you are using.

Comment: I got it to work, it for some reason didnt work on the first insert but when I ran any other insert into()... it worked fine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your trigger is syntactically incorrect. Multiple-statement trigger code **must** be enclosed with BEGIN-END block:

```sql
delimiter //
create trigger age_verify
before insert on customers
for each row
BEGIN
    if new.age < 0 then 
        set new.age = 0;
    end if;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

But in your particular case you do not need in BEGIN-END and DELIMITER, use simple

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER age_verify
BEFORE INSERT ON customers
FOR EACH ROW
SET NEW.age = GREATEST(NEW.age, 0);
```

Comment: One benefit of using the `if` is that it avoids updating unnecessarily.

Comment: @SOS ??? there is no any update in this trigger, it only replaces one variable (column) value with another. In memory.

Comment: No, not the keyword `update`, update in the generic sense, i.e. modify the `NEW.age` value. There's no need to modify the value if it's already >= 0

Comment: @SOS `NEw.age` modifying is not an update, this is common value assignment. Like `SET x = 1;`. But in general you're correct, when IF can prevent fake operation execution then it should be used.

Comment: I think you're still misunderstanding me :-)  I probably should have used used a different word to avoid confusing the general concept with an actual UPDATE.  Bottom line, it does work that isn't always necessary. (Edit) I think we're on the same page now about IF

Comment: @SOS This is true but I predict that you'll detect the speed difference never, it is too low, less than measuring accuracy.

Comment: True, but it's not always about speed. It's more about being aware of what the code does and it's pros/cons.

Answer (score 0):

```
delimiter //
    create trigger age_verify before
    insert on Customers
    for each row
    begin
    if new.age < 0 then set new.age = 0;
    end if;
    end
 //
delimiter ;
```